# Why are all fields vector spaces over themselves?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Apparently, all fields are vector spaces over themselves.

But the definition of a vector space involves the operation of *vector addition* and *scalar multiplication*, and elements of a vector space are considered to be *vectors*.

So, when we say that all fields are vector spaces over themselves, are we in that instant considering the elements of the field to be vectors (where we might not have been when we were considering the field in relation to a separate vector space)? I get that once you just take vector addition to be regular field addition, scalar multiplication to be field multiplication and  field elements to be vectors the axioms are satisfied, but no one seems to mention this move.

Comment: You are correct: "once you just take vector addition to be regular field addition, scalar multiplication to be field multiplication and field elements to be vectors the axioms are satisfied".

Comment: OK, but the elements of R, for example, are numbers, right? So why are we now taking them to be vectors without comment?

Comment: @DanÖz They're numbers and they're vectors. They're not mutually exclusive concepts.

Comment: You may have the misconception of what a vector is. A vector is, by definition, an element of a vector space. That's it. So if the elements of a vector space happens to be functions, then those functions are vectors. If we have a vector space formed by sets, then those sets are vectors. If the elements of a vector space are numbers, then numbers are vectors. There's nothing off about it.

Comment: For instance, take the field $\mathbb R$. If you agree with the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is an n-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$, then the case $n = 1$ is what you're describing.

Comment: @DanÖz  Numberphile once said to Asaf Karagila that a "number" is an abstract way to represent a quantity. A vector space is by itself a set with addition and external composition defined on it such that they satisfy axioms. The elements of the set are just symbols   . For example I can define a vector space over a set of two elements say $\{a,b\}$ and the field being $\Bbb{Z}_{2}=\{0,1\}$ . Now I can define addition to be $b+a=a+b=a$ and $a+a=b+b=0$ , $0\cdot a=0\cdot b=0$ and $1\cdot a=a=a\cdot 1$ and $1\cdot b= b =b\cdot 1$ . Notice that I can take $a$ and $b$ to be anything .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Your construction forces $b=0$ so it can't be arbitrary. This is unsurprising since vector spaces require a zero vector so either $a$ or $b$ had to fill that role.

Comment: @CyclotomicField By "anything" I meant that it is just a symbol. Of course $b$ is the "zero" element. I meant that instead of writing it as "b" or $0$ we can write it as any symbol we want(say a smile face)  . So even though they are not necessarily "arrows with magnitudes" , they are vectors as they satisfy the axioms.